# Access Metadata of Next.js App Directory in Component

Tags: next.js13

I'm new to the Next.js app directory (but know the page directory).

When I add the Metadata at the page.tsx like this:

```
export async function generateMetadata({ params: { lang } }: { params: { lang: Locale } }, parent: ResolvingMetadata) {

    const dictionary = await getDictionary(lang);

    return {
        title: dictionary.pages.home.title,
    };    
}
```

And have a component Header.tsx for example (to place in the layout.tsx), I would like to get access to the page title so I can show this in the header. I tried searching for an answer but couldn't find anything.

As an example:

```
'use client';
export default function Header() {
    const metadataTitle = metadata.title;

    return (
        <p>
            {metadataTitle}
        </p>
    );
}
```

I tried searching for a way to access this metadata object but failed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access the metadata in the component. You have to re-fetch the data in anyplace you want. and Next.js will not send multiple requests but will get it from the cache.